# Arp Scan results to delimited file with pipe delimiter

Tags: awk, sed

Have a file with arp-scan results that looks like this for each line:

```
192.168.103.216   c4:2f:90:e5:8d:31    Hangzhou Hikvision
```

I want to go through and add a pipe delimiter after the IP address and after MAC address so final file will look like this:

```
192.168.103.216|c4:2f:90:e5:8d:31|Hangzhou Hikvision
```

Different ARP scans will produce different IPs and MACs so I have to match on the pattern of an IP address and a MAC address and put a | after the IP address and after the MAC address. Or I could just put a | at the beginning of the MAC address and the End of the MAC address.  Result would be the same.

I know sed can match an IP address with something like:

```
sed '/\n/!s/[0-9.]\+/\n&\n/;/^\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}[0-9]\{1,3\}\n/P;D'
```

Am thinking I can match a MAC address with a similar statement only using `[0-9A-Z:]` as a pattern.

Should be semi easy to go through the file and add the delimiters.  Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if your file is exactly like that, and for conciseness, with GNU awk:

```
awk '$3=$3" "$4{NF--}1' OFS=\| file
192.168.103.216|c4:2f:90:e5:8d:31|Hangzhou Hikvision
```

And if the hostname can have more than one spaces:

```
awk '{for(i=4;i<=NF;i++)$3=$3" "$i;NF=3}1' OFS=\| file
```

Comment: The second awk statement works like a charm as the hostname/manufacture column can have more than one space.  Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT:*** Adding solution which will take care of spaces remomal too. Completely based on shown samples only. One more thing this solution will only print lines with pipe after ips and mac address if both matches found else it will simply print the line.

```
awk --re-interval '
{
  $1=$1
}
match($0,/([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+ /){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-1)"|"
  $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
}
match($0,/([[:xdigit:]]+:){5}[[:xdigit:]]+ /){
  print val substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-1)"|" substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  next
}
1
'  Input_file
```

---

---

Could you please try following(tested with provided samples only, with GNU `awk`, we could shorten it too but since I have old version of `awk` I will try to add it later).

```
awk '{sub(/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/,"&|");sub(/[[:xdigit:]]+:[[:xdigit:]]+:[[:xdigit:]]+:[[:xdigit:]]+:[[:xdigit:]]+:[[:xdigit:]]+/,"&|")} 1' Input_file
```

OR above code's regex could be shorten to as follows too.

```
awk --re-interval '{sub(/([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+/,"&|");sub(/([[:xdigit:]]+:){5}[[:xdigit:]]+/,"&|")} 1' Input_file
```

OR with using `gsub` and mentioning regex in single gsub itself.

```
awk --re-interval '{gsub(/([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+|([[:xdigit:]]+:){5}[[:xdigit:]]+/,"&|")} 1' Input_file
```

In case you want to save output into Input_file itself then append `> temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file` to above code too.

---

---

***`sed` solution:*** Tested with GNU `sed`.

```
sed -E 's/([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+|([[:xdigit:]]+:){5}[[:xdigit:]]+/&|/g' Input_file
```

***NOTE:*** I am using `--re-interval` since it is old else you could remove it, if you latest version of `awk` with you(GNU `awk`)

Comment: All the examples work great on my debian machine.  They do not deal with white space between the fields as the accepted answer does, but I did not really make that request in my original question.

Comment: @WilliamK, ok, assuming that your Input_file is same as shown samples if this is the case then could you please try following. Again- it considers that your Input_file is exactly same s shown samples: `awk --re-interval -v OFS="" '{$1=$1;gsub(/([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+|([[:xdigit:]]+:){5}[[:xdigit:]]+/,"&|")} 1'  Input_file` let me know then? PS: + point of these codes is it field numbers are NOT hardcoded so anywhere IPs or Macs will be concatenated with `|`.

Comment: @WilliamK, please check my EDIT command once and let me know then if that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `awk`; it makes the process much simpler.

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS = "|" } { $1 = "" $1; print }'
```

Change the output field separator from white space to a pipe symbol.  Then print the inputs, but you have to change something to trigger a reformatting with the new OFS, and prepending an empty string to `$1` achieves that.